# Make a single record from multiple SQL

Tags: sql, libreoffice

My end objective is to create a flat output file / table to export.
I have two tables I want to bring together as follows.

Person table (Unique for AccountId)

```
AccountId
Name
```

I have a second table called BillDt (many to accountid - could be more that 2)

BillDt table

```
AccountId
BillDt
```

Output result wanted is: AcctId, Name, 1stBillDt, 2ndBillDt

I don't care if the 2ndBill date is actually the last one if there are 3 or more.
I can put the result back in the person table or into a new table.
Looking for SQL to do this.  I'm using LibreOffice Base 4.0.3

Comment: what's the structure in your BillDt table? Is there a column to note it's the 1st or 2nd entry?

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: Dan, I'm using HSQL under LibreOffice Base 4.0.3.  There is no column in BillDt to indicate 1st or 2nd entry.  I built the BillDt table from a CSV file.  I could bring the CSV into a spreadsheet, sort on AcctId and BillDt then create the table with a sequential primary key.  You wouldn't know the value of the primary but you'd know the lower date would have a lower primary value.  Not sure if that would help.  Thanks for getting back to me.  Dave

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something denoting the 1st, 2nd, 3rd entries in your BillDt table you could use something like below

```
SELECT person.accountID, person.Name, CASE WHEN BillDt.OrderKey = 1 THEN BillDt ELSE '' END AS 1stBillDt, CASE WHEN BillDt.OrderKey = 2 THEN BillDt ELSE '' END AS 2ndBillDt
FROM Person
 INNER JOIN Person.AccountID ON BillDt.AccountID
```